# Looping for a specific value from list but only have something to search by

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay im trying too find the connection too get the right element by loop.

My goal is to find 5627 from list3. But i can only use 168 from variable "a" and use one of the lists in the 3 lists to filter by. The answer is too use the first list becouse it got relation with variable a and list 3.

```
a = 168

List_of_3_lists = [[5628,168,5627],[2342,553,3113],[4532, 332,2442]]

list3 = [4322, 5627, 3313]
```

I have tried a lot but maan this should be easy but im failing.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, this is not a Python list.

Comment: This is not the code, its the question

Comment: I had some trobule posting without doing this

Comment: Your question and the relationship of the lists is unclear.  Can you edit your question and post the actual code for the 3 lists in question?

Comment: Okay ill try hold up

Comment: `list2` should be dict `{168: 5627, 553: 3113, 332: 2442}`

Comment: If a = 2342, what will be the result?

Comment: The result should be 5627 from list 3. You hva to use for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem statement is unclear but, if I'm guessing correctly, you want to select the first list in `list_of_3_Lists` that contains `a` (168) then find the first intersection of that list with `list3`.

If that is the case, then you can do it with a list comprehension:

```
next( n3 for n3 in list3 for lo3 in List_of_3_lists if a in lo3 and n3 in lo3 )

# 5627
```